# Nuget and "Unable to load the service index"

Tags: c#, linux, nuget, monodevelop

I'm having a trouble with Monodevelop. I'm using LinuxMint Serena (18.1) and Monodevelop 7.0.1 (build 24). When trying to add nuget package on a new project, I get the next answer:

```
[nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json. An error occurred while sending the request
Error: SecureChannelFailure (Object reference not set an instance of an object) Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

I check the api nuget address and is normal, nothing strange about the link. I tried to copy the old package from the original Visual Studio project but remain the problem.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
After trying many things with no success, I use the old nuget packages downloaded from the old Visual Studio project. I don't know if making that works or the fact that I take the project and open it up with Monodevelop for Windows fixed the issue.

Comment: I check both links and not solve my quiestion. The first one is related to Visual Studio, I'm using Monodevelop on Linux environment. I changed to `http://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json` and persists the error.  
The second one not even has answers.

Comment: Looks like you are running into a Mono v5 bug - https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=57019 A workaround is to set legacy TLS provider and then run flatpak from the same command line `export MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=legacy`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same question in ubuntu(16.04) Monodevelop(7.0.1). I can access to http://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in my browser, but when I add nuget package in monodevelop, it throw the exception, " Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json".
I solve this problem by checking the updater, check and install all software updates.
You can try it. Good luck!